# Codeigniter associative array - changing array name in a foreach loop

Tags: php, arrays, forms

I've set up the associative array for the codeigniter form, and I've run into a problem with having a foreach loop around the data.

I have this code - and I've now just realised I'm re-declaring the variable name $array_name as an array rather than a string which is why this one isn't working:

```
foreach ($search as $search_term){
$count++;
$array_name = '$search'.$count;

$array_name = array(
        'name'  => 'search'.$count,
        'id'    => 'search'.$count,
        'value' => set_value('search'.$count, $search_term),
        'maxlength' => 80,
        'size'  => 30,
        'class' => 'text-input',
);
```

}

However the array name is being logged as $array_name and not as $search1, so I'm obviously doing something wrong and I was hoping someone could point me in the right direction!

I've also tried this:

```
foreach ($search as $search_term){
$count++;
$array_name = '$search'.$count;

'search'.$count = array(
        'name'  => 'search'.$count,
        'id'    => 'search'.$count,
        'value' => set_value('search'.$count, $search_term),
        'maxlength' => 80,
        'size'  => 30,
        'class' => 'text-input',
);
```

}

This is what I am looking for as the final outcome, but there will be six overall:

```
$search1 = array(
        'name'  => 'search'.$count,
        'id'    => 'search'.$count,
        'value' => set_value('search'.$count, $search_term),
        'maxlength' => 80,
        'size'  => 30,
        'class' => 'text-input',
);
$search2 = array(
        'name'  => 'search2',
        'id'    => 'search2',
        'value' => set_value('search2, $search_term),
        'maxlength' => 80,
        'size'  => 30,
        'class' => 'text-input',
);
```

EDIT 1:

I've just realised I'm re-declaring the variable name $array_name as an array rather than a string which is why the first one isn't working, but I'm still a bit stuck as to how to do it.

Comment: Why don't you keep creating one array with sub-arrays like `$searchs[0]` would be your first search array, etc. ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

to make a variable using a dynamic string use `${'somestring'} =`

```
foreach ($search as $search_term){
    $count++;
    $array_name = '$search'.$count;

    ${'search'.$count} = array(
        'name'  => 'search'.$count,
        'id'    => 'search'.$count,
        'value' => set_value('search'.$count, $search_term),
        'maxlength' => 80,
        'size'  => 30,
        'class' => 'text-input',
    );
}
```

Though using an associative array would be better

```
$searches = array();
foreach ($search as $search_term){
    $count++;
    $array_name = '$search'.$count;

    $searches['search'.$count] = array(
        'name'  => 'search'.$count,
        'id'    => 'search'.$count,
        'value' => set_value('search'.$count, $search_term),
        'maxlength' => 80,
        'size'  => 30,
        'class' => 'text-input',
    );
}

print_r( $searches );
```